# Slideshare not working in web view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am opening an html in my web view. The html contains a slideshare in which there is buttons for next and previous slides. Html opens perfectly but on clicking on buttons nothing happens. Ideally it should show the next/previous slide on clicking on buttons. 
below is the code -

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

In java -

```
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        Spanned formatedHtml = Html.fromHtml(htmlText);
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", formatedHtml.toString(),
                "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you setting plain text in WebView?

Comment: so what should i place there? can u update the code. thank you

Comment: As far as i know Slideshare is online presentation collection. Slideshare has embedding feature, here's an example url: "http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/32203434".
Just remove last three lines (including Spanned fromatedHtml) and write so:
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/32203434");

Comment: Its also not working. I used -       WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/32203434");      But still not working, its not even showing the page

Comment: Did you include "http://"? stackoverflow has removed it

Comment: yes I tried with both, but same problem exists.

Comment: i am now able to load that url.and slide share is also working on that url. but on other slide share is not working.